# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError after adding aar into android studio

Tags: android, manifest, noclassdeffounderror, aar

I have added aar into android studio and trying to access one of the activity from aar into my project.
I am to import that activity but at the run time I am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: .

The step that I followed to add aar:

1) imported an aar using file menu option.
2) then I added that library from module setting to my project.

I am able to all the activities which are there in aar in my main project manifest merge file.

whats going wrong, guide me

Comment: is your aar dependencies are provided  in your main project !?

Comment: yes like this :    implementation project(':project_name-release')

Answer (score 1):

**AAR Integration**

1. Add aar file in libs folder of your app (Just copy and paste)
2. Inside `build.gradle` of your app module:

   a) Add following code:

   ```
   repositories {
       flatDir {
               dirs 'libs'
       }
   }
   ```

   b) Add aar dependency:

   ```
   compile(name: 'your-aar-filename-without-extension', ext: 'aar')
   ```

After adding above dependency, Kindly Sync Project with Gradle Files.

Comment: performed above steps, still getting activity not found at runtime